# Maximo Anywhere - Dynamic List Creation using Work Execution App

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am customizing Anywhere(7.5.2)-WorkExecution. I am trying to create a dynamic list on the Work Log execution but it always creates only one. Kindly help.

[CREATE Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKgqJ.png)

[Work Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKgqJ.png)

File: WorkLogHandler.js
Function: _saveTransaction

Existing Code:

```
_saveTransaction: function(){
try{
      var workOrderSet = CommonHandler._getAdditionalResource(this,"workOrder");
      var workOrder = workOrderSet.getCurrentRecord();
if (!workOrder.isNew()) {
ModelService.save(workOrderSet);
} 
this.ui.hideCurrentView();
}catch(e){
throw e;
}
},
```

New Code:

```
_saveTransaction: function(){
debugger;
try{
      var workOrderSet = CommonHandler._getAdditionalResource(this,"workOrder");
      var workLogdata = CommonHandler._getAdditionalResource(this,'workOrder.workloglist').getCurrentRecord();
      var workOrder = workOrderSet.getCurrentRecord();
      debugger;

      for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
      debugger;
      if (!workOrder.isNew()) {
     debugger;
     workLogdata.set('summary',i+" Round");
     } 
      ModelService.save(workLogdata);
     this.ui.hideCurrentView();
      }
return;
}catch(e){
throw e;
}

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create a new worklog entry every time the record is saved, the issue is here..

var workLogdata = CommonHandler._getAdditionalResource(this,'workOrder.workloglist').**getCurrentRecord();**

You need to create a new record for each new worklog that you're trying to add, not retrieve the current one.

var workLogdata = CommonHandler._getAdditionalResource(this,'workOrder.workloglist').**createNewRecord()**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.

I tried the same but getting an new issue that for the second iteration, the LOGTYPE becomes NULL

Also, It  doesn't saved in Maximo Asset Management as well. Please help.